# Update Fields in Record Using Forms Command Button

Tags: forms, ms-access, sql-update

I'm new to MsAccess.
I have a table named "Tracking" which contains some fields including "OrderID", "Process1_In" and "Process1_Out".

I created a form which creates records with "OrderID" and "Process1_In".
I'm creating another form where users input an "OrderID" into a textbox named "OrderID" and click the command button where this updates the "Process1_Out" field in the Tracking table with the current date and time (using the Now() function).

I created the codes in the Form_BeforeUpdate event as follow:

```
 Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

 Update Tracking 

      Set Process1_Out = Now()

      Where OrderID = OrderID.Value

 End Sub
```

However this doesn't update the record as planned. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is a string that you build, then execute. So your code would look like this:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim sql as string
    sql = ""
    sql = sql & "Update Tracking "
    sql = sql & "Set Process1_Out = #" & Now() & "# "
    sql = sql & "Where OrderID = OrderID.Value"
    CurrentDB.Execute sql
End Sub
```